# Why http server doesn't respond after 6 times request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, keep-alive

[environment]
node.js
express

My server is stopped to responding for my request after 6 times.

Below the img, show my status...

first img is normal status.

normal status img
[image]

second img is error status( nothing response ).
error status img(1)

[image]

error status img(2)
[image]

What should i do?

my codes related server

```js
const { app } = require('../app'); // set up express.router
const port = require('../settings.json').http.port; //port 3000
const httpServer = require('http').Server(app);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || port);


//set port
httpServer.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: Looks like your process in `/api/v1/conference/{id}` is expensive and maybe synchronous, so the server may be hanging until it is resolved. Can you share a minimum product sample to reproduce your behaviour?

Comment: can you reply my answer? i have added some codes in answer

Comment: Show the code which is handling the route /api/v1/conference/{id} .....

Comment: sorry, i have added the codes, but it's blocked. i'm checking now...